# "Hello, World" in PHP

Tags: php

It's a ["Hello, World"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) code snippet. I have tried to run it using [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), and I am using [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) to write the code. Upon execution, the page does not display "Hello, World!". What would have went wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World | Hello and Welcome</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            Echo "Hello, World!";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it called something.php? Did you check your webservers error logs?

Comment: For me this code runs. It's probably wrong server configuration.

Comment: Well then, what do you see? The title only? Are you sure you are running it from localhost properly?

Comment: @Rikudo: Yes, just the title and the blank page. I am not sure about the configuration but Xampp runs fine.

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer Then rename it to index.php - usually, .html-files are not bound to the php-handler for performance reasons.

Comment: If there had been wrong configuration, I might not have got the title too..

Comment: Why a -1? Isn't it a valid problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to execute PHP code on an HTML page. All PHP files should have the .php extension (implied from the OP's comments). Change your filename.

PHP handlers don't work in .html pages for efficiency reasons. When you use .html instead of .php, you are telling the server not to embed PHP in that page, to save server resources.

Answer (score 3):

`Echo` would be better as `echo`.

Is the file extension .php, not .html?

Is PHP configured on the web server?

Please check all those out.

Answer (score 2):

Either you're not saving the file in a php extension so the PHP engine doesn't run on it or your server isn't set up properly

[It's working fine on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/hb0Iu)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to change the extension to .php is correct, because by default it would be a waste of server resources to actually read every file to see if it contains PHP code in order to decide whether it should execute PHP processing on it.

That said if you really wanted to you can probably configure the server to serve up any file extension as PHP, even a made up one. There's nothing magical about the extension other than how it's configured to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

for hello world program in php just follow this tutorial
 
but before that you should have wamp server or xamp server on your pc
(wamp/xmap are open source software's and easily can found on google)
your 1st php program code:-

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

output:-
hello world
Tutorial :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qtqzhdEX-c 
after this tutorial you can able to move other intermediate level programs of php.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is generally case sensitive (see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

So try changing `Echo` to `echo`.

Comment: If you were to check, you'd find that this isn't the case and `Echo` works perfectly fine.

Comment: only PHP's variables are case sensitive.

Comment: actually it appears as though variables, constants, array keys, class properties, and class constants are case sensitive whether user or PHP defined. I have not personally found  mention of case sensitivity in the documentation with regard to language constructs such as `echo`. This is why I said "generally case sensitive."